# PostgreSQL: Delete key/value pair from array with json objects

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-12

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE movies( id text, data jsonb );

INSERT INTO movies(id, data) VALUES (
  '1', 
  {
      "actors": [
        {
            "name": "actor1",
            "email": "actor1@somemail.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "actor2",
            "email": "actor2@somemail.com"
        }
      ]
  }
);
```

What I want is to delete the **email** field (key + value) from each json object of the actors array.

I've tried the following solution and although it does execute, it doesn't have any effect on the array at all:

```
update movies
set data = jsonb_set(data, '{actors}', (data->'actors') - '{actors, email}')
where id = '1';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To manipulate *all* items in the array, you will need to use a subquery:

```
UPDATE movies
SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{actors}', (
  SELECT jsonb_agg(actor - 'email')
  FROM jsonb_array_elements(data->'actors') actor
))
WHERE id = '1';
```

([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c12d317f2476c402509eda697b03533a))

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify indexes individually to delete the array element `email`

```
update movies
   set data = jsonb_set(data, '{actors}', data -> 'actors' #- '{0,email}' #- '{1,email}')
 where id = '1';
```

the path element `{1,email}` might be replaced by `{-1,email}` (*Negative integers count from the end*).

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=63d5c3080b4c063c86e0f5302fb21b8c)</kbd>